# Use one app for multiple Facebook tab applications

Tags: asp.net, facebook, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, facebook-graph-api

I need to use my Facebook web app for multiple page tab applications.
So i can't use web.config for retrieving Facebook application Id and Secret. I need to know from which application was redirected to my virtual directory. Facebook pass signed_request parameter to my app, but in signed_request i don't have Facebook application id.
My question is: how i can know in this case of which app request arrives?
How i can get requested app id?

I have "fbsr_" parameters in request. But Request contains all application ids was requested. So i cant use it:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I found a Facebook application not pass any data apart from signed_request. signed_request does not contain appId. Single way to implement this task is pass application id parameter by my self, and get it from route values on server.